# installing mongodb with pecl

Tags: mongodb, pecl, bitnami

this is what i get:

```
bitnami@ip-10-117-57-211:/bin$ sudo pecl install mongo

downloading mongo-1.4.0.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.4.0.tgz (138,495 bytes)
..............................done: 138,495 bytes
84 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php appears to have a suffix /bin/php, but config variable php_suffix does not match
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
Can't load '/opt/bitnami/perl/lib/5.8.8/i686-linux/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so' for module Data::Dumper: /opt/bitnami/perl/lib/5.8.8/i686-linux/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so: undefined symbol: PL_sv_undef at /opt/bitnami/perl/lib/5.8.8/i686-linux/XSLoader.pm line 70.
 at /opt/bitnami/perl/lib/5.8.8/i686-linux/Data/Dumper.pm line 36
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm line 33.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm line 33.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/autom4te line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/autom4te line 38.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Do you have the php development packages installed?

Comment: do you have the php dev packages installed?

Comment: I believe they are installed already. How can i get the version of the dev package?

Answer (score 4):

Try configuring manually as it seems bitnami is a bit funky:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autoconf unzip wget
```

Download the latest source code from the web page, uncompress it and compile the module.

```
$ wget http://pecl.php.net/get/mongo-1.4.3.tgz
$ tar -zxf mongo*
$ export PHP_AUTOCONF=/usr/bin/autoconf
$ export PHP_PREFIX=/opt/bitnami/php
$ cd mongo-*
$ /opt/bitnami/php/bin/phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Adapted from: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/PHP#How_to_install_OAuth_module.3f

Answer (score 1):

well i finally got it working. I ran through the steps to install mongo extension on mac server and it worked for my bitnami lamp stack.

The instructions were on this blog:
http://andres.jaimes.net/857/setup-php-mongo-on-mac/

Comment: Could you elaborate on things here, in your answer?

Comment: pecl wasn't working for me on bitnami lamp stack. So downloading the mongo php extension using CURL then phpize fixed my problem. I pretty much just followed the same instructions listed in the mongo on mac link i posted.